# Exporting table of daily temperature (ERROR: Internal Error)

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, features, reducers

I am trying to download a table of daily temperature for the year of 2001 and all Brazilian municipalities in Google Earth Engine Code (GEE). After mapping a Reduce Regions function and flatten to convert in a table, I hit Export to Drive, and it runs for a while (it's a lot of information) but I end up with an internal error. I've tried lots of different code but always ending with this error. I don't think it is a problem in my code. Can anyone help me?

```
// Script for daily temperature and precipitation extraction for all Brazilian municipalities
// 30/06/2020

// Importing Brazilian municipalities feature collection
var munBrazil = ee.FeatureCollection("users/rodrigoccuri/BRMUE250GC_SIR");

// Importing MODIS Terra Land Surface Temperature daily global 2001

var modisTerra = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1").select(['LST_Day_1km']).filterDate('2001-01-01', '2002-01-01');

// Creating function for Image Collection reduction

var reduceTemp = function(imagemodis){
  return imagemodis.reduceRegions(munBrazil, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000);
};

// Maping the function to all image collections

var munModis = modisTerra.map(reduceTemp);

// Flattening the collection of collections into a table

var tableMunModis = munModis.flatten();

// Printing the fisrt element to check it out

print(tableMunModis.first());

// Exporting to csv file

Export.table.toDrive(tableMunModis, 'temp2001', 'GEE', 'temp2001');
```

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Yes, my bad! I just updated there, GEE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you print the first element to the console, you can see that it still has its geometry attached. If you try to export these features in a table, one of the columns of the resulting CSV will contain the coordinates of the 1000+ vertices in GeoJSON format. I'll assume that you don't need or want these in with your timeseries values.

Try this to set the geometry to `null` for each element:

```
var tableMunModis = munModis.flatten();

var removeGeometry = function(el) {
  return ee.Feature(null, {'CD_GEOCMU':el.get('CD_GEOCMU'), 
                           'NM_MUNICIP':el.get('NM_MUNICIP')});
};

var table2 = tableMunModis.map(removeGeometry);
// Printing the first element to check it out
print(table2.first());
// Export
Export.table.toDrive(table2, 'temp2001', 'GEE', 'temp2001');
```

When you print the first element from `table2` it loads much faster in the console. I think this will speed up the overall export and hopefully remove the internal error you encountered.

Comment: That was a great tip, thanks! I didn't pay attention on this. But unfortunately, I got the same problem. I gonna try with different pcs though, maybe is something with my computer ( I am pretty new to GEE, so trying every possible solution).

Comment: One other thing to check - do you have a folder in your Google Drive named 'GEE'? I think if that folder doesn't exist the export will fail. If you want to change that directory, you can adjust the last line of code: `Export.table.toDrive(table2, 'temp2001', 'path/to/GDrive/directory', 'temp2001');`

Comment: Yes, I have. I gonna change the directory just in case. Do you think I can export directly to OneDrive for example or my pc instead of google drive?